# Injecting cookies using PHP not yielding the same cookie

Tags: php, http, cookies, http-headers, setcookie

I'm trying to make a PHP script that sets cookies to the browser by reading them from a file first. In the file is the piece of HTTP header "Cookie: x=foo; y=bar; etc". The script does a cleanup of the string so we end up with only the variable name (x) and the value of the variable (foo). The problem is when I set the cookies from the file, using Wireshark I see the exact values of the variables being sent to the broser. When I see what cookies the browser sends to the page, they are different, i.e I set cookie x=foo;, then the browser sends it back to the page as Cookie: x=bar. Do you know what may be causing this? When I use the Greasemonkey script for injecting cookies everything works fine tough.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    function inject($what)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($what);$i++)
        {
            $name = $what[$i][0];
            echo "injecting cookie named \"$name\" .... <br> ";
            setrawcookie($what[$i][0], $what[$i][1]);
        }
    echo 'all cookies injected properly, ready';
    }

    $newcook=file("/home/todor/cook.txt");
    echo '<pre>';
    for ($i=0; $i<count($newcook); $i++)
        $newcook[$i] = str_replace('Cookie: ', '', $newcook[$i]);      
    $newcook = explode('; ', $newcook[0]);

    for($i=0;$i<count($newcook);$i++)
        $newcook[$i] = explode('=', $newcook[$i]);
    for($i=0;$i<count($newcook);$i++)
        echo 'cookie variable name "'.$newcook[$i][0].'" with value of "'.$newcook[$i][1].'"<br>';

    echo '</pre>';
    inject($newcook);
    ?>

---------------Cookies being set----------------------

Set-Cookie: MoodleSession=h0j51hvrkvu30mdeu3d9321thit8c8pdkle66llr2lipj80chjb0
Set-Cookie: __utma=16796069.1074685784.1352477410.1352477410.1352477410.1
Set-Cookie: __utmc=16796069
Set-Cookie: __utmz=16796069.1352477410.1.1.utmcsr

---------------Cookies being sent to the server -----------

Cookie: MoodleSession=hn92mn8vhl6kvg7f8qogpgm8reeisnoope27o7q3ivrecnr84gb1; __utma=16796069.1720416199.1352484234.1352484234.1352484234.1; __utmb=16796069.1.10.1352484234; __utmc=16796069; __utmz=16796069.1352484234.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Comment: A cookie is more than just the name=value pair. I'd say it would be useful if you add the whole cookie-lines to your question so the problem becomes more clear. +1 for checking with wireshark.

Comment: thanks for the tip, the output is now in the code :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question, but why do you loop over the same array four times, instead of looping over it once, doing four things to each item?

Comment: Okay, place `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` at the very top of your PHP code. It's highly likely that you're echoing after headers have been send. This error reporting will make it visible.

Comment: I'm not getting any more output after adding the 'ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);' line